# Openstack impossible to connect to Internet from instances or to instances from host

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

I installed Openstack (all-in-one) by using KAYOBE. I follow all configuration steps described here https://docs.openstack.org/kayobe/latest/installation.html and here https://docs.openstack.org/kayobe/latest/configuration/scenarios/all-in-one/overcloud.html#configuration

Everything seems fine network/floating IPs, flavors,images,instances but I still have an issue to reach Internet from my instances and also to reach the instances from the host.

I have 2 instances in my Openstack with for each a floating IP in 192.168.213.xxx/24

I can ping from both instances their floating IP and their local IP.
I can also ping from both instances the public interface of my pubic network (EXT)

Any idea or support would be welcome.

Thank you.

My configuration is this one:

```
On my host the network interfaces are the following:

brens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.213.36  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.213.255
        inet6 fe80::ec5d:5cff:fee4:e865  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:26:9f:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 975109  bytes 2110124730 (1.9 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 607990  bytes 243846445 (232.5 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

docker0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.17.0.1  netmask 255.255.0.0  broadcast 172.17.255.255
        ether 02:42:ec:7a:b0:c6  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

ens33: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::20c:29ff:fe26:9fe3  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 00:0c:29:26:9f:e3  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1793551  bytes 2197893693 (2.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 706011  bytes 252766868 (241.0 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Boucle locale)
        RX packets 48961080  bytes 56924742056 (53.0 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 48961080  bytes 56924742056 (53.0 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p-brens33-ovs: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::9040:7aff:fe13:333e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 92:40:7a:13:33:3e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 83424  bytes 9297973 (8.8 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 30  bytes 2056 (2.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

p-brens33-phy: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet6 fe80::ccf3:e0ff:fe09:eeb  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether ce:f3:e0:09:0e:eb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 30  bytes 2056 (2.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 83424  bytes 9297973 (8.8 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

qbr24033e67-96: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        ether 1a:08:1a:6e:23:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 90  bytes 6932 (6.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

qbr2aa4f6fc-67: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        ether 66:d4:18:69:3b:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 79  bytes 5618 (5.4 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

qvb24033e67-96: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::1808:1aff:fe6e:23fc  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 1a:08:1a:6e:23:fc  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 189  bytes 19262 (18.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 190  bytes 15978 (15.6 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

qvb2aa4f6fc-67: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::64d4:18ff:fe69:3b12  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 66:d4:18:69:3b:12  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1567  bytes 185484 (181.1 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1654  bytes 154488 (150.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

qvo24033e67-96: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::c411:18ff:fe38:f94a  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether c6:11:18:38:f9:4a  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 190  bytes 15978 (15.6 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 189  bytes 19262 (18.8 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

qvo2aa4f6fc-67: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::8c85:c4ff:fe68:8145  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 8e:85:c4:68:81:45  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1654  bytes 154488 (150.8 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1567  bytes 185484 (181.1 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap24033e67-96: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fee4:c722  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:16:3e:e4:c7:22  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 168  bytes 14342 (14.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 201  bytes 18968 (18.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tap2aa4f6fc-67: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::fc16:3eff:fef6:8f99  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fe:16:3e:f6:8f:99  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1632  bytes 152852 (149.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1587  bytes 186940 (182.5 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tapbdd8182b-15: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1450
        inet6 fe80::f816:3eff:fe61:78d5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether fa:16:3e:61:78:d5  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 24  bytes 1776 (1.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

```
Host: VMWARE Workstation 16

My WM where is installed my Openstack Instance:
-----------------------------------------------

 - Operating System: CentOS 8 
 - Selinux deactivated 
 - Firewalld service inactive

One single network interface setup in NAT with a static IP address:
IP: 192.168.213.36/24
DNS1: 192.168.213.2 (DNS from my VMWARE Workstation network)
DNS2: 8.8.8.8
GATEWAY: 192.168.213.2
```

My Openstack network configuration file:

**FROM /etc/neutron directory:**

```
##################
File: ml2_conf.ini
##################
[ml2]
type_drivers = flat,vlan,vxlan
tenant_network_types = flat,vlan,vxlan
mechanism_drivers = openvswitch,l2population
extension_drivers = port_security,dns

[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges =

[ml2_type_flat]
flat_networks = physnet1

[ml2_type_vxlan]
vni_ranges = 1:1000

#################
File neutron.conf
#################
[DEFAULT]
debug = True
log_dir = /var/log/kolla/neutron
use_stderr = False
bind_host = 192.168.213.36
bind_port = 9696
api_paste_config = /usr/share/neutron/api-paste.ini
api_workers = 1
metadata_workers = 1
rpc_workers = 2
rpc_state_report_workers = 2
metadata_proxy_socket = /var/lib/neutron/kolla/metadata_proxy
interface_driver = openvswitch
allow_overlapping_ips = true
core_plugin = ml2
service_plugins = metering,router,vpnaas
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:uUmeMPEtFFu6IIQNoJ4Kdl026ZEG9TvlT5PdZnR9@192.168.213.36:5672//
dns_domain = sample.openstack.org.
external_dns_driver = designate
ipam_driver = internal

[nova]
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
region_name = Toulouse
project_name = service
username = nova
password = wxXLLtG3uRpUxExM3YJvCsofbmPMWFy0RbnZ92Wk
endpoint_type = internal
cafile =

[oslo_middleware]
enable_proxy_headers_parsing = True

[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/neutron/tmp

[agent]
root_helper = sudo neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf

[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://neutron:zRMXmINpPXB7QNBSROcks7MuWdzbYw3TIouRbI7m@192.168.213.120:3306/neutron
connection_recycle_time = 10
max_pool_size = 1
max_retries = -1

[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://192.168.213.120:5000
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = IujTCY3xxrnATYsc5BLw7MMDOjsvktHkaxnJvWux
cafile =
region_name = Toulouse
memcache_security_strategy = ENCRYPT
memcache_secret_key = vUHcQln5CqIRRbnABG6D4MO81Fb6jVEum4gPPMvY
memcached_servers = 192.168.213.36:11211
memcache_use_advanced_pool = True

[oslo_messaging_notifications]
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:uUmeMPEtFFu6IIQNoJ4Kdl026ZEG9TvlT5PdZnR9@192.168.213.36:5672//
driver = messagingv2
topics = notifications,notifications_designate

[designate]
url = http://192.168.213.120:9001/v2
auth_uri = http://192.168.213.120:5000
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
project_name = service
username = designate
password = ngYG2ZLmGwfdfWHgSq4u0fqZz1s4fGmIola9pfL9
allow_reverse_dns_lookup = True
ipv4_ptr_zone_prefix_size = 24
ipv6_ptr_zone_prefix_size = 116
cafile =
region_name = Toulouse

[placement]
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
username = placement
password = fJmE67U1r91mM0n7PqvgI0JJ55qjbBxem1qahJuL
user_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
project_domain_name = Default
os_region_name = Toulouse
os_interface = internal
cafile =
region_name = Toulouse

[privsep]
helper_command = sudo neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf privsep-helper

################
File config.json
################
{
    "command": "neutron-server --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf  --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf ",
    "config_files": [
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/neutron.conf",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/neutron.conf",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/neutron_vpnaas.conf",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
                {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/ml2_conf.ini",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        {
            "path": "/var/log/kolla/neutron",
            "owner": "neutron:neutron",
            "recurse": true
        }
    ]
}

#################
File config.json
#################
{
    "command": "neutron-server --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf  --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf ",
    "config_files": [
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/neutron.conf",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/neutron.conf",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/neutron_vpnaas.conf",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/neutron_vpnaas.conf",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
                {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/ml2_conf.ini",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        {
            "path": "/var/log/kolla/neutron",
            "owner": "neutron:neutron",
            "recurse": true
        }
    ]
}
```

***From /etc/neutron-openvswitch-agent***

```
################
File config.json
################
{
    "command": "neutron-openvswitch-agent --config-file /etc/neutron/neutron.conf --config-file /etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini",
    "config_files": [
        {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/neutron.conf",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/neutron.conf",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        },
                {
            "source": "/var/lib/kolla/config_files/openvswitch_agent.ini",
            "dest": "/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/openvswitch_agent.ini",
            "owner": "neutron",
            "perm": "0600"
        }
    ],
    "permissions": [
        {
            "path": "/var/log/kolla/neutron",
            "owner": "neutron:neutron",
            "recurse": true
        }
    ]
}

#################
File neutron.conf
#################
[DEFAULT]
debug = True
log_dir = /var/log/kolla/neutron
use_stderr = False
bind_host = 192.168.213.36
bind_port = 9696
api_paste_config = /usr/share/neutron/api-paste.ini
api_workers = 1
metadata_workers = 1
rpc_workers = 2
rpc_state_report_workers = 2
metadata_proxy_socket = /var/lib/neutron/kolla/metadata_proxy
interface_driver = openvswitch
allow_overlapping_ips = true
core_plugin = ml2
service_plugins = metering,router,vpnaas
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:uUmeMPEtFFu6IIQNoJ4Kdl026ZEG9TvlT5PdZnR9@192.168.213.36:5672//
dns_domain = sample.openstack.org.
external_dns_driver = designate
ipam_driver = internal

[nova]
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
region_name = Toulouse
project_name = service
username = nova
password = wxXLLtG3uRpUxExM3YJvCsofbmPMWFy0RbnZ92Wk
endpoint_type = internal
cafile =

[oslo_middleware]
enable_proxy_headers_parsing = True

[oslo_concurrency]
lock_path = /var/lib/neutron/tmp

[agent]
root_helper = sudo neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf

[database]
connection = mysql+pymysql://neutron:zRMXmINpPXB7QNBSROcks7MuWdzbYw3TIouRbI7m@192.168.213.120:3306/neutron
connection_recycle_time = 10
max_pool_size = 1
max_retries = -1

[keystone_authtoken]
www_authenticate_uri = http://192.168.213.120:5000
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
project_name = service
username = neutron
password = IujTCY3xxrnATYsc5BLw7MMDOjsvktHkaxnJvWux
cafile =
region_name = Toulouse
memcache_security_strategy = ENCRYPT
memcache_secret_key = vUHcQln5CqIRRbnABG6D4MO81Fb6jVEum4gPPMvY
memcached_servers = 192.168.213.36:11211
memcache_use_advanced_pool = True

[oslo_messaging_notifications]
transport_url = rabbit://openstack:uUmeMPEtFFu6IIQNoJ4Kdl026ZEG9TvlT5PdZnR9@192.168.213.36:5672//
driver = messagingv2
topics = notifications,notifications_designate

[designate]
url = http://192.168.213.120:9001/v2
auth_uri = http://192.168.213.120:5000
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
auth_type = password
project_domain_id = default
user_domain_id = default
project_name = service
username = designate
password = ngYG2ZLmGwfdfWHgSq4u0fqZz1s4fGmIola9pfL9
allow_reverse_dns_lookup = True
ipv4_ptr_zone_prefix_size = 24
ipv6_ptr_zone_prefix_size = 116
cafile =
region_name = Toulouse

[placement]
auth_type = password
auth_url = http://192.168.213.120:35357
username = placement
password = fJmE67U1r91mM0n7PqvgI0JJ55qjbBxem1qahJuL
user_domain_name = Default
project_name = service
project_domain_name = Default
os_region_name = Toulouse
os_interface = internal
cafile =
region_name = Toulouse

[privsep]
helper_command = sudo neutron-rootwrap /etc/neutron/rootwrap.conf privsep-helper

##########################
File openvswitch_agent.ini
##########################
[agent]
tunnel_types = vxlan
l2_population = true
arp_responder = true

[securitygroup]
firewall_driver = neutron.agent.linux.iptables_firewall.OVSHybridIptablesFirewallDriver

[ovs]
bridge_mappings = physnet1:brens33-ovs
datapath_type = system
ovsdb_connection = tcp:127.0.0.1:6640
local_ip = 192.168.213.36
```

Openstack Security groups link attached to the instances network

```
[root@controller0 kolla]# openstack security group show be8d2de7-6bd4-4702-9b9f-c3e0f96d451a
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field           | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| created_at      | 2021-07-31T12:06:30Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| description     | Project-00000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| id              | be8d2de7-6bd4-4702-9b9f-c3e0f96d451a                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| location        | cloud='', project.domain_id=, project.domain_name=, project.id='8d4b5b9558d64a04b34b797db97157bf', project.name=, region_name='Toulouse', zone=                                                                                                |
| name            | Project-00000                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  |
| project_id      | 8d4b5b9558d64a04b34b797db97157bf                                                                                                                                                                                                               |
| revision_number | 6                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| rules           | created_at='2021-07-31T12:06:57Z', direction='ingress', ethertype='IPv4', id='5a896360-c712-4c93-bda9-be669662915e', port_range_max='22', port_range_min='22', protocol='tcp', remote_ip_prefix='0.0.0.0/0', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:06:57Z' |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:06:45Z', direction='ingress', ethertype='IPv6', id='7e8642ed-05d2-44a1-9034-216856d21492', protocol='ipv6-icmp', remote_ip_prefix='::/0', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:06:45Z'                                          |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:06:31Z', direction='egress', ethertype='IPv6', id='85074747-5623-4142-86a3-045bf3b84ce6', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:06:31Z'                                                                                          |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:06:38Z', direction='ingress', ethertype='IPv4', id='86270591-3ad2-4feb-a278-5c2a5968fd27', protocol='icmp', remote_ip_prefix='0.0.0.0/0', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:06:38Z'                                          |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:06:31Z', direction='egress', ethertype='IPv4', id='8fa6cb0e-7616-4b0e-9662-887dd012e777', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:06:31Z'                                                                                          |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:07:05Z', direction='ingress', ethertype='IPv6', id='acd0daab-a5b7-4eb3-9e2b-5c848f546ba6', port_range_max='22', port_range_min='22', protocol='tcp', remote_ip_prefix='::/0', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:07:05Z'      |
| stateful        | True                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| tags            | [u'Project-00000', u'TrashProject']                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
| updated_at      | 2021-07-31T12:07:05Z                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

[root@controller0 kolla]# openstack security group show 88e4c862-eed0-4884-b205-defd8a50c67b
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Field           | Value                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| created_at      | 2021-07-31T12:05:25Z                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| description     | Default security group                                                                                                                                                                                         |
| id              | 88e4c862-eed0-4884-b205-defd8a50c67b                                                                                                                                                                           |
| location        | cloud='', project.domain_id=, project.domain_name=, project.id='8d4b5b9558d64a04b34b797db97157bf', project.name=, region_name='Toulouse', zone=                                                                |
| name            | default                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
| project_id      | 8d4b5b9558d64a04b34b797db97157bf                                                                                                                                                                               |
| revision_number | 1                                                                                                                                                                                                              |
| rules           | created_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z', direction='egress', ethertype='IPv4', id='26b1decc-0515-436a-a3a6-445e93c1797c', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z'                                                          |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z', direction='ingress', ethertype='IPv6', id='508e85c3-1bac-4407-903b-92be818e012b', remote_group_id='88e4c862-eed0-4884-b205-defd8a50c67b', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z' |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z', direction='egress', ethertype='IPv6', id='51abe797-cead-4790-86ee-3341af0253de', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z'                                                          |
|                 | created_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z', direction='ingress', ethertype='IPv4', id='591c792d-c8c6-4282-8f6e-f66c9cc1c0f7', remote_group_id='88e4c862-eed0-4884-b205-defd8a50c67b', updated_at='2021-07-31T12:05:26Z' |
| stateful        | True                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
| tags            | []                                                                                                                                                                                                             |
| updated_at      | 2021-07-31T12:05:26Z                                                                                                                                                                                           |
+-----------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Network topology**

[image]

**One port of the network**

[image]

I can see on my host where openstack (docker) is , and with tcpdump, that icmp requests are well received from the VM instances, but on VM instances I did not see any ICMP reply.

[image]

Comment: Please check this. Very similar case.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/68643508/14795385

Comment: @ehcp Thank you. I am not familiar with iptables, in my case I have only one interface called ens33.Which masquerade rules I have to setup in my iptables? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Up !!! Is someone can help to find a clear settings to install openstack by using kayobe on VMWare workstation. My question is mainly about the network settings with one single ethernet card on my VM. To try to go forward about the issue that I have not yet solved. Thank you for your support.