# Why is it not possible to ping a real machine to a vm inside openstack

Tags: openstack, devstack

I created a vm (vm-devstack-01) using Vagrant and Virtualbox in which I installed Devstack. The vm has an enp0s3 interface in NAT mode and an enp0s8 interface in bridge mode. The real network I use in my house is 192.168.88.0/24. This network uses DHCP addressing.

vm-devstack-01:

[image]

I set FLOATING_RANGE from local.conf to 192.168.88.224/27.

My local.conf:

```
[[local|localrc]]
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
DATABASE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
RABBIT_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD
HOST_IP=192.168.88.43
FLAT_INTERFACE=enp0s8
FLOATING_RANGE=192.168.88.224/27
FIXED_RANGE=10.11.12.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
```

Later I created a debian VM (vm-debian-01) on openstack which received floating ip 192.168.88.230.

Also, the security group releasing the ping was created:

`Ingress    IPv4    ICMP    Any 0.0.0.0/0`

With this configuration it was possible to ping vm-devstack-01 to vm-debian-01 created inside openstack.

[image: ping]

But I can't ping from the real machine (my notebook - IP 192.168.88.28) to vm-debian-01. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: The culprit may be VirtualBox or the bridge that was created by VirtualBox. It seems to block traffic to addresses that are unknown to VirtualBox. Years ago, I had this problem as well. When I switched to an identical OpenStack setup on a KVM virtual machine, the problem went away. You could use Wireshark and Tcpdump to find out at what point traffic is blocked.

Answer (score 0):

You need MASQUERADE definitions on your Openstack host machine.
That is, network translation for packets to-from your VM.
At the same time, you need routing to your Openstack host from all other networks that you want to reach VM's.

- Masquerade rules
- Routing
- Proper Security Group settings in Openstack